# How often will a FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger execute if the operation is caused by an FK constraint with UPDATE CASCADE?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, foreign-key, postgresql-9.2

I understand that a trigger on table t defined with `FOR EACH STATEMENT` will run once when I execute an `UPDATE t ...`.

Now, when `t` is defined with `FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCES a ... ON UPDATE CASCADE`, and I update N rows in `a`, will that cause the trigger to be called once, or N times?

Put differently, are changes to a table cascaded by an FK constraint more like a single `UPDATE`, or more like a series of `UPDATE`s?

Comment: You could create a test case! Insert into another table in the body of the trigger and see how many rows you get. Then write it up in your own answer to this question (that's allowed, encouraged even)!

Comment: The leading sentence mentioning `FOR EACH STATEMENT` is orthogonal to the rest of the question. FK constraints are implemented with special triggers `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: @Erwin "FOR EACH ROW of a" or "FOR EACH ROW of t"?

Comment: @ypercube: I added an answer with details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are currently implemented with special internal triggers. All of them are run ***`FOR EACH ROW`***.

Note that these are implementation details that can change, so don't rely on it. But the basics have not changed over the last couple of major versions, so major changes are unlikely.

I ran a quick test with a simple FK constraint from `tbl` to `tbltype`. A simple FK is implemented with four simple internal triggers `FOR EACH ROW` in my test on pg 9.4.
Here is a quick rundown on how to investigate:

```
SELECT oid  -- 74791
FROM   pg_constraint
WHERE  conrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
AND    contype = 'f';

SELECT objid, classid::regclass  -- 74792,74793,74794,74795 / 'pg_trigger'
FROM   pg_depend
WHERE  refobjid = 74791
AND   deptype = 'i'

SELECT tgrelid::regclass, tgname, tgfoid, tgtype FROM pg_trigger
WHERE  oid IN (74792,74793,74794,74795) ORDER BY tgfoid;

'tbl'    ;'RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_74794';1644;5
'tbl'    ;'RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_74795';1645;17
'tbltype';'RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_74792';1654;9
'tbltype';'RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_74793';1655;17

SELECT oid, proname FROM pg_proc
WHERE oid IN (1654,1655,1644,1645);

1644;'RI_FKey_check_ins'
1645;'RI_FKey_check_upd'
1654;'RI_FKey_noaction_del'
1655;'RI_FKey_noaction_upd'
```

Two internal "noaction" triggers on `tbltype`.
Two internal "check" triggers on `tbl`.
All of them are run ***`FOR EACH ROW`***, as indicated by odd numbers in **`tgtype`**.

The 2 bytes of the Postgres `tgtype  smallint` represent an `int16` in C source code where the least significant bit encodes `TRIGGER_TYPE_ROW`. Detailed explanation here:

- [Meanings of bits in trigger type field (tgtype) of Postgres pg_trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635033/939860)

You can easily test this with a pair of identical triggers where you only change `FOR ROW` / `STATEMENT` ...

Answer (score 6):

It does execute N times, and the easiest way to see this is to execute the statement with an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` prepended, i. e.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE UPDATE a SET col = 1 WHERE othercol = 'foo';
```

This will give you information similar to this:

`Trigger for constraint t_col_fk on a: time=1.300 calls=9`

*(tested with 9.2)*

Comment: This is somewhat surprising to me.  Tested on 9.4 with the same results.